# ActiveRecord/sqlite3 column type lost in table view?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sqlite, types

I have the following ActiveRecord testcase that mimics my problem. I have a People table with one attribute being a date. I create a view over that table adding one column which is just that date plus 20 minutes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

%w|pp rubygems active_record irb active_support date|.each {|lib| require lib}

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
:adapter => "sqlite3",
:database => "test.db"
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :people, :force => true do |t|
    t.column :name, :string
    t.column :born_at, :datetime
  end

  execute "create view clowns as select p.name, p.born_at, datetime(p.born_at, '+' || '20' || ' minutes') as twenty_after_born_at from people p;"

end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class Clown < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Person.create(:name => "John", :born_at => DateTime.now)

pp Person.all.first.born_at.class
pp Clown.all.first.born_at.class
pp Clown.all.first.twenty_after_born_at.class
```

The problem is, the output is

```
Time
Time
String
```

When I expect the new datetime attribute of the view to be also a Time or DateTime in the ruby world. Any ideas?

I also tried:

```
create view clowns as select p.name, p.born_at, CAST(datetime(p.born_at, '+' || '20' || ' minutes') as datetime) as twenty_after_born_at from people p;
```

With the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after more investigation, I found that:

MySQL works:

```
%w|pp rubygems active_record irb active_support date|.each {|lib| require lib}

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => "mysql",
    :username => "root",
    :database => "test2"
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :people, :force => true do |t|
    t.column :name, :string
    t.column :born_at, :datetime
  end

  execute "create view clowns as select p.name, p.born_at, (p.born_at + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) as twenty_after_born_at from people p;"
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class Clown < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Person.create(:name => "John", :born_at => DateTime.now)

pp Person.all.first.born_at.class
pp Clown.all.first.born_at.class
pp Clown.all.first.twenty_after_born_at.class
```

Produces:

```
Time
Time
Time
```

Reading the sqlite3 adapter source code, I found out that it uses PRAGMA table_info(table_name) to get the type information, and that does not return the types for views:

```
sqlite> pragma table_info('people');
0|id|INTEGER|1||1
1|name|varchar(255)|0||0
2|born_at|datetime|0||0
sqlite> pragma table_info('clowns');
0|name|varchar(255)|0||0
1|born_at|datetime|0||0
2|twenty_after_born_at||0||0
```

Therefore it may be a limitation of the adapter or just a sqlite3's views limitation. I have [opened a ticket for ActiveRecord](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/4544-rails3-activerecord-sqlite3-lost-column-type-when-using-views#ticket-4544-2):

Also, [quoting this mail](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg12590.html) in sqlite-users:

> RoR should be using the
>   sqlite3_column_type() API to determine
>   the type of the values returned from a
>   query. Other APIs like
>   sqlite3_column_decltype() and pragma
>   table_info are returning other
>   information, not the type of the
>   result value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically there is no datatime type in SQLite as opposed to MySQL. In your example you explicitly define types for the table but do not specify types for the view. That might be the problem. Can not check it since I have never touched ruby.

Comment: The problem is both RoR and sqlite3. The first uses table_info PRAGMA for views when it knows sqlite3 can't give you the types of a view. It should use sqlite3_column_type on the result set (but it seems the types in ActiveRecord are resolved only once for a table). 
Sqlite's fault is not providing the types in the view, when they could be mapped to the origin table, and in this case, to the result of the datetime() function (MySQL can, at least).